# How to display message if SQL query returns nothing or times out in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have an old VB6 application where I had to optimize the query run times.  I succeeded in doing this, but I want to add a field to display a message if the query returns nothing or if the query times out.
Can you post a link or show some sample code that could help?  I have almost no experience with VB6 or ADO so any help or direction would be appreciated.

Here is the code that executes the query.

```
'Execute the query.
If ADOConnect(moConn, moParms) Then
    Set moRS = moConn.Execute(sSql)
End If
```

Here is what I came up with so far.

```
'Test if results are null
If IsNull(sSql) Then
    MsgBox "null"
```

Thanks

Comment: I figured it was something simple.  Any check for if the query timesout?  We have that issue occasionally.  With several hundred thousand records, the queries can take up to 3 min..

Comment: Have you look at the ConnectionTimeout property : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676718(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Perhaps with the On Error Resume Next : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327610/resolving-an-ado-timeout-issue-in-vb6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
moConn.ConnectionTimeout = 300
If ADOConnect(moConn, moParms) Then
    Set moRS = moConn.Execute(sSql)
End If

If moRS.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "no record"
```

Comment: Would the timeout message be: If moConn.ConnectionTime = true Then MsgBox "Query Timed Out"?

Comment: Why would you want to show a message instead of avoiding the timeout ?

Comment: If the timeout is avoided, would the query not stop running?  I want a message to display to the user if the query did not complete

Comment: Why the query will stop if there is no timeout arising ? The query will stop when it is complete...

Comment: I'm saying if the query is stopped due to a timeout, I would like a message displayed to the user instead of just stopping the application and leaving the user wondering what happened.

Comment: I understand this, what I asked is : Why do you want to keep the timeout ? Why not just give more time to your connection to let it finish the query ? If the query is always supposed to return rows, so you will know that something goes wrong if the RecordCount = 0

Comment: We have had instances where we have an issue with the connection and it will run for literally 30 min.  The query should never take more than 5 min.  It appears the query "timesout" and will basically freeze up.  I guess I'm looking for something like: If moConn.ConnectionTime = true Then MsgBox "Query Timed Out".

Comment: This code will stop the query after 5 minutes. Look at my previous answer for hint to handle the timeout

Answer (score 0):

```
If moRS.EOF then
    MsgBox "null"
End If
```

To loop through it :

```
Do While Not moRS.EOF
   dim colA = moRS("colA")
   moRs.MoveNext()
Loop
```